# Momentum of Flying birds

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

When birds poop during flight, does it increase their velocity due to conservation of momentum and Newton's Third Law?

Comment: Depends which direction they poop in

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the poop leaves the bird. If it if just dropped, then no, because the bird is not exerting any force. If it is "shot out", then yes there would be a force on the bird that could give somewhat of a propulsion. Whether or not this would be strong enough to cause a noticable difference is another question though.